# Windows 10 File Explorer- File Metadata not showing

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, pdf, metadata, file-search

Recently moved a user from Win 7 to Win 10 (fresh win10 install) and for some reason after installing apps on the win10, when I add a column to display any type of file medatada like; TAGS, Author or any other detail we use and file explorer will not populate the metadata for a file. This happens regardless if its a office type file, PDF or image.

For example, PDFs we use Title column for sorting/search and when we open the PDF on its proper editor (Foxit or Adobe Pro) metadata is there.

Has anyone had this issue before if so how did you guys resolved it?

After searching the internet, there seems to be a tool that populates metadata, but when you edit this metadata in Foxit Editor, for example, the characters get all weird.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a windows indexer issue.  I would make sure of the C drive is being indexed.

Hit start and type "Indexing Options" select modify, and make sure the entire C drive is being indexed.  This should help out with populating those fields.

As a side not, if you are using bitlocker (or a similar tool to encrypt your files, you will need to go into the Advanced section of the indexing options and select "Index Encrypted Files"

Good Luck!